# How do you map the payload in angular 5 using the HttpClient and redux

Tags: angular, redux

How would I do the equivalent of this call in my service using HttpClient instead of Http?  HttpClient doesn't the map() call.

```
loadObservations() {
  this.http.get(`${BASE_URL}${1000}`)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map(payload => ({ type: 'ADD_OBSERVATIONS', payload }))
    .subscribe(action => this.store.dispatch(action));
}
```

Comment: The same way, except you dont need `.map(res => res.json())` anymore, since HttpClient observables emit the json body by default. This is documented. Why don't you read the documentation? https://angular.io/guide/http, https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.map` is actually the method of `Observable` which comes from `RxJS` (a library for reactive-style programming which is used by Angular internally).

Since `HttpClient`'s `get` method returns an `Observable`, it means you can apply the `map` operator to it. The `HttpClient` (unlike the deprecated `Http` from `HttpModule`) extracts the response as JSON for you so the only thing that changes from the snippet you posted is that you should remove `res => res.json()`. It will break since the received object is deserialized from a JSON string and therefore does not contain the custom function `json()` that you're trying to invoke.